# Как работают Stream API под капотом?

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Использую их довольно давно.

Но какой механизм внутри лежит, мне так и непонятно. В том числе вызывало удивление, что данный код определения наличия заданного текста  работает на порядок быстрее для больших файлов (~17 миллионов строк), чем классический BufferedInputStream. При этом код становится гораздо более читабельный.

```
Files.lines(path).filter((line) -> line.contains(keyWord)).findAny();
```

Comment: а можете показать кусок функции как вы читаете из файла и сравниваете ?